# Run command in terminal from IntelliJ External Tools

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to run a command in the OSX terminal using the IntelliJ Idea External Tools. I don't want the command to run in the IntelliJ terminal.

This is what should happen when I run the tool:

- The OSX terminal opens in a separate window
- The command I want (with parameters) runs in the OSX terminal
- The results of the command are displayed in the OSX terminal
- The terminal is NOT closed afterwards

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

This should be possible, however, I don't have a mac to test this on.
This is how you would do it in Windows. Maybe you can translate to the OSX equivalents.

```
Program cmd.exe
Parameters /c start "" cmd.exe /k dir
Working directory $FileDir$
```

`cmd.exe` is the terminal so substitute the OSX terminal command here.

`/c` passes commands to cmd.exe then exits

`start "" cmd.exe` is a Windows command to start an application `""` means no title and `cmd.exe` says we are going to launch the command window again.

`/k` means do the command and then stay open

`dir` is the command I am doing (same as `ls`)

`$FileDir$` is the IDEA macro for the the directory of the file you are clicking on. You can change this to other macros to what fits your need.